How to authorize in react micro-frontends
I am working on a project which has two separate micro-frontends. let's say MF1 & MF2.
They both has to be included in one container app.
I am using react(create react app) for each micro-frontend. Each app has their own react-router-dom
How they should be developed.
Container App -> / * container app should contain all the micro-frontends. should work like a wrapper for all the micro-frontends.
Micro-Frontend App 1 -> /orders * all the routes which starts with '/orders' should be in separate micro-frontends.
Micro-Frontend App 2 -> /cart * all the routes starts with '/cart' should be in this MF.
Micro-Frontend App 3 -> /admin * all the routes for '/admin' should be a separate MF.

Each micro-frontend will have separate state management. (preferably redux)

Let's say we are using some JWT Token which is used to authorize the user. In normal apps we store it in localStorage or in cookies. Now how can i access those values across multiple apps ?
How can I maintain Autherization among multiple apps which has separate state management ?
Please reply/comment if you know anything related to micro-frontends.
Thanks in advance.
i'm trying to use monorepo to manage them all in single repo. I do not have any idea how autherization works between micro-frontends. I know that autherization will be handled in backend services (micro-services)
